# async function passed as props, event handler could not call this function

Tags: reactjs

I'm passing a async function from App to Header to Form. I cant seems to call that function with submit event handler even with the use of arrow function.

I've tried fat arrow function. The only working way is to move the function down to Form which it work but not ideal as I need the data to be stored in App state. when I `console.log(result)` I get undefined

```
class Form extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {value: ''};
    }
    handleChange=(e)=> {
        this.setState({value: e.target.value});
      }
    handleSubmit= (e)=>{
        e.preventDefault();
        const value = this.state.value;
        this.props.getResult(value)
    }
    render(){
        return (
            <form className="search"onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <input type="text" className="search__field" placeholder="Search over 1,000,000 recipes..." value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                <button className="btn search__btn"></button>
            </form>
        ); 
    }

}
```

App component

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      search:[],
    }
  }

  getResult = async (query) =>{
    try {
      const key = 'key';
      const res = await axios(`https://www.food2fork.com/api/search?key=${key}&q=${query}`);
      const result = res.data.recipes;
      console.log(result)
      // if(result) this.setState({search: result});
    }
    catch (err) {
      alert(err);
    }
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="container">
        <Header getResult={this.getResult}/>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Header

```
class Header extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.getResult = this.props.getResult;
      }
    render(){
        return (
            <div className="header">
                <Logo />
                <Form getResult={this.getResult}/>
                <Like />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this code... The error must be elsewhere... Maybe post the other two components involved as well...

Comment: Okey, I've edited the post

Comment: So for one thing it's `axios.get(...)` The rest seems to be fine other than you should not share your api key like this and also the error it's giving is limit meaning you've hit the limit on your API

Comment: ahh yeah, that is the problem, thank you @SakoBu. My stupid mistake.

Comment: You're welcome...